# Linear Algebra Done Right, Exercise 5.B.9 - solution verification?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ is finite dimensional, $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$, and $v \in V$ with $v \neq 0$. Let p be a nonzero polynomial of smallest degree such that $p(T)v=0$. Prove that every zero of $p$ is an eigenvalue of T.

Factor $p(z) = (z - \lambda_1)\ldots(z - \lambda_m)\ldots(z-\lambda_n)$. Then, we have: $p(T)v = (T - \lambda_1)\ldots(T - \lambda_m)\ldots(T-\lambda_n)v=0$

Suppose that $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_m$ are not eigenvalues, and that the remaining $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues. Therefore $(T -\lambda_1I)\ldots (T-\lambda_mI)v \neq 0$, as each of the factors are injective and so have null space equal to $\{0\}$. However, the polynomial long division of $\frac{p(z)}{(z - \lambda_{m+1})\ldots (z - \lambda_n)} = 0$, implying that $(T -\lambda_1I)\ldots (T-\lambda_mI)v=0$, a contradiction.

So, all zeroes of $p$ are eigenvalues of $T$.

How did I do on this?

Comment: Looks OK, though I would remove bottom half since it is not needed.

Comment: Unless you're assuming that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ (or some other algebraically closed field), you cannot assume that the polynomial factors completely into linear factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sammy Black's comment says, you can't assume the minimum polynomial factors into linear factors.

Assume $\lambda$ is a zero of $p$. We will show $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

Write $p(x)=(x-\lambda)q(x)$ where $q$ is a non-zero polynomial with degree necessarily less than $p$. Since $p$ is the *minimum* polynomial, there is some vector $w$ such that $q(T)w=v\neq0$.

Then $0=p(T)w=(T-\lambda I)q(T)w=(T-\lambda I)v=Tv-\lambda v$. Since $v$ is non-zero, this proves $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.